# How to implement authentication security in WCF?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

How to implement authentication security in WCF?

Means if any user is registered, than only be able to use service.

One way:-
Like, a mobile application at the time of installation update unique key with application Database. 
So when client tried to connect with WCF service and if the key match then only be able to connect with service.

I want to know is there some other way to prevent unauthorized access for service?

Comment: Will this service be hosted in IIS?  Are the expected users associated with a domain credential?  Will these services be available only internally or will the be externalized to the Internet?

Comment: hosted in IIS.No users are not ssociated with a domain credential.  its in internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read through this link [Programming WCF security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx).

Read this link to [Implement CustomUserNamePassword Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx)

You can configure your bindings to perform CustomUsernamePassowrd Authentication where you validated if the username and password are valid and if so you grant access to the service else deny.

Comment: thanks for revert rajesh. But this WCF is access by mobile app users.users just have to install app and use this service. I mean how CustomUsernamePassowrd Authentication will help to handle it?

Comment: When a user registers his username password would be stored on your DB which you can access from your service. So when a user installs the app on his mobile and the application is tryinh to access the web service the application needs to send his username pwd as part of the request to authenticate the user on the server to access the web service.